# Can't initialize mysql after building it from sources

Tags: mysql

Just built MySQL from sources, on Windows, and trying to run:

```
mysqld --initialize
```

It seems that the process just freezes and never returns.
It created a data folder with a *.err file inside, with the following text:

```
2018-10-12T16:02:43.838418Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] E:\dev\mysql-server-8.0\bld\runtime_output_directory\Debug\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.12-debug) initializing of server in progress as process 12584
```

But nothing happens... it's just stuck.

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you a) building it from source, and b) expecting us to debug what you're trying to build without any information?

Comment: @KenWhite, to explore the code. Just wanted to see if anyone ran into the same issue.. if you have any ideas on which further information will be useful, feel free to share and I'll be happy to provide it :)